# Why CSS file is not loading when my web page gets loaded in a WKWebView, until I put a delay on the request

Tags: css, ios, swift, font-awesome, wkwebview

I am developing an `iOS` app that mainly loads my web pages in `WKWebView`.

Things were fine so far before I start facing a weird issue with one of the CSS file not loading.

The `font-awesome.css` file is not loading, generally it gets loaded on the very first page call. In my knowledge nothing has been changed on the server side that could affect loading of `font-awesome.css` file.

I am intercepting request by implementing following function in iOS app code. But for the first request I just do `decisionHandler(.allow)` because I don't want any interception for the first request.

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, 
       decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Swift.Void) {

    // For the first request it will go as is
    decisionHandler(.allow)    
}
```

Once the first page gets loaded on `WKWebView` the `font-awesome.css` file didn't get loaded hence some font icons are shown as squares on the page.

After spending some time on this issue I tried to put a delay on calling `decisionHandler(.allow)` as follows and then it starts loading the `font-awesome.css` file:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.150) {
    // I just added a delay of 150 ms and it starts loading the css file.
    decisionHandler(.allow)
}
```

For me currently its very confusing to figure out the relation between putting a delay and loading of the css file.

I need suggestion on this behavior why its happening or is there anything else due to which this is happening and I am just doing a work around by putting a delay.

**Some more updates:**

1. I have an Android app also that is loading same web pages in WebView and that is working fine.
2. I check the IIS logs by sending the request with and without putting the delay. With the delay I an clearly see in IIS logs that it loads the font awesome as follows, but in without delay I don't see this entry in IIS logs:

> 2020-11-23 13:44:36 10.100.2.72 GET
> /Content/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2 v=4.5.0 80 - 10.100.0.111
> ....